# How to allow more width in algorithm

Tags: margins, algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I am using the algorithm2e package, and I have an algorithm (shown in image) in which one line is split into two (namely, the assignment of alpha on line 21 goes over two lines). I would like to not have this. Is there a way to increase the allowable width of the algorithm so that the right margin (blue line in diagram) is extended further to the right?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered finding more compact expressions for the very long, and currently well nigh indecipherable, formulas?

Comment: @Mico No, plus the formula isn't that long. It's just a double summation less than or equal to another summation